# Allow indexing subdirectories but not root directory

Tags: .htaccess, web-hosting

I have a site where subdirectories are generated automatically, and need to be indexable under .htaccess

However, I don't want someone to be able to go to the root of these subdirectories and to view them all. I also don't want anything other than these subdirectories to be indexable.

E.g.

> / ~ Has "`Options -Indexes`" (Non-Indexable)
>
> /foo/ ~ Has "`Options -Indexes`" (Non-Indexable)
>
> /foo/bar/ ~ Has "`Options +Indexes`" (Indexable)
>
> /foo/baz/ ~ Has "`Options +Indexes`" (Indexable)

It's not possible for me to generate an individual .htaccess file for every subdirectory individually, the system I'm using doesn't support it.

Comment: I guess I could add a redirect so if they visit the root (i.e. /foo) it just sends them away, but it seems like a half solution.

Comment: What _system_ are you using?

Comment: It's a closed source gameserver management system that doesn't let you change the template/generation method for these subfolders.
It's taking files, compressing them, and moving them to subfolders in public_html, based on the server the files came from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's no other way to solve this problem (without possibly using the Apache config), so I'm just allowing the index recursively (i.e. from /foo), then inside /foo 's .htaccess file:

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo[/]?$
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
```

To just redirect people to the homepage. Also put a meta refresh redirect in there just incase.